# grid layout vs table control?

Tags: wpf

I need to display in my program number of similar statistics, like:

```
Name / Age / Salary / Position
John   30     1000    senior
Kate   18     100     intern
...     ..    ..       ...
```

Totally I need to display several hundreads lines.

The question is what control should I use?

At least I know two options:

- use Table control
- use Grid layout (then dinamically add labels etc. to the grid)

I think with Grid I will automatically have "custom rendering" because I can add anything into Grid, not only "Label", but also buttons for example. However I'm not sure if I need such possibility.

But I need ability to sort the table by certain column.

So it seems "Table" better feets my needs, however I noticed that it seems that "Table" is not very popular in WPF (am I correct? why?)

So the question is "Should I use Table or there is someting better?" Is it possible to use databinding with Table?

I'm absolutely novice to WPF so sorry for any stupid questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) or a [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) (with [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx)), do **not** use a `Grid`, and what is this `Table` you speak of? If you mean [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table.aspx), that can only be used in flow documents, which you do not need.

*(See the documentation pages for examples or do some searching)*

Comment: I think this is the table http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/working-with-wpf-table-using-xaml-part-i/

Comment: @javapowered: That is a flow content control, not such a good choice in my opinion.

Comment: thanks! and what is prefferable between DataGrid and ListView?

Comment: @javapowered: ListView is a lighter control and mostly for presenting data, DataGrid is more powerful as it is designer for editing as well. Further it can generate columns automatically. Read the documentations, there are some examples, or search a bit elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid and GridView were built for exactly that.  When you bind a source it creates a table like row for each row in the source.